# Why is assigning a function object returning a empty string

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to learn functional programming and I see that when I return

```js
const profile = {
  name: 'qw',
  children: [{
    name: 'peter',
    getName() {
      return this.name;
    }
  }],
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
};
const val = profile.getName();

console.log(`output is ${val}`); //I get 'qw' as expected


//However if I try 

const val1 = profile.getName;
console.log(`output is ${val1()}`); //I get ''
```

I am not sure why this is returning different things on not using '()'

Comment: The issue is `this` does not refer to what you think it does in the `console.log` string template context.

Comment: In short, in your second code snippet `this === window`, so you are getting `window.name`

Comment: I understand that , I am just not sure why using `()` helps me out ? Why not the one I entered first.

Comment: @leo check the dupe but in short `profile.getName()` will have `this === profile` so `name === "qw"` while `const val = profile.getName; val()` will execute with `this === window` and thus `this.name` will be `window.name`.

Comment: I mean why is this referring to the window variable @vlaz

Comment: @leo I can't recomment checking the dupe more, it goes in depth. But just to shorten it - JS has delayed context initialisation, so `this` will be given a value *at the time of invocation*. It will have the value you invoke it from. When you get the function handle via `const val = profile.getName;` you lose the original context which is `profile` in your first example. When there is no context, `window` is used by default. Or rather, the global object which, in browsers, is `window`. You can see more details about this in the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @VLAZ's comment, `const val = profile.getName();` returns the result of the invocation (`this` is within the `profile` context) while `const val = profile.getName;` just references `getName` in `profile`.When you do invoke it, then the context is `window`.

In other words `profile.getName()` executes (using the correct `this`) while `profile.getName` does not execute. And when it does, the context is `window`

```js
const profile = {
    name: 'qw',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'peter',
            getName() {
                return this.name;
            }
        }
    ],
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
};
const val = profile.getName();
// this is the equivalence of "qw" which is the result of invoking `getName`

console.log(`output is ${val}`); // 'qw'

const val = profile.getName;
// this is the equivalence of:

  getName() {
     return this.name;
   }
// And the context here is the window.   
console.log(`output is ${val}`); // ''
```

Comment: The context doesn't "change" - it's only set at the time the call is made. So when `profile.getName()` runs, it will invoke `getName` with a context of `profile`. When running `getName` with no context (in the second example), the context is set to `window`. There is no change - `this` inside the body of `getName` was never a concrete thing, it would always be determined at a later point.

Comment: Great point. Scope in JS is a bit tricky. Most explanations are too convoluted and it's often times difficult to fully understand (clearly I have some knowledge holes). I think the OP's confusion lies with invoking `getName` i.e. `getName()` vs `getName`

Answer (score 0):

Despite the short syntax, `getName()` is still just a regular function, which happens to be stored in an object. It does not carry an object reference around, `this` is evaluated when/where/how you call it:

```js
var obj1={
  test:"This is obj1",
  logTest(){console.log(this.test);}
};

obj1.logTest();

var fun=obj1.logTest;
fun();
var test="This is window";      // in browsers, regular variables on the top-level
fun();
window["test"]="Indeed it is";  // are actually members of window
fun();
this.test="All the same";       // really they are
fun();

var obj2={
  test:"This is obj2",
  testfun:fun
};
obj2.testfun();

//////////////////////////////////////
console.log("--------");

var boundfun=obj1.logTest.bind(obj1);
boundfun();

var obj3={
  test:"This is obj3",
  testfun:boundfun
};
obj3.testfun();
```

However the last part, `boundfun()`, shows a method of function objects, [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which you can use to "pre-parametrize" a function, where the first parameter you can set is the `this`. I also suggest checking the other two methods linked on the left side of that page, [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), both are about invoking a function via not just passing its arguments, but also freely setting `this`. So you could create your own `bindthis()` if you wanted to:

```js
var obj1={
  test:"This is obj1",
  logTest(){console.log(this.test);}
};

function bindthis(fun,diz){
  return function(){
    fun.call(diz);
  }
}

var boundfun=bindthis(obj1.logTest,obj1);

boundfun();

var obj2={
  test:"This is obj2",
  testfun:boundfun
};

obj2.testfun();
```

Side note: the question is not really about functional programming, `this` is an object-oriented concept. So what you see is more like one particular mix of functional and object-oriented programming.